# Black grout leaves porcelain tile pockmarked

Tags: flooring, tile, grout

I am applying Prism Charcoal color grout to this [exact brand of small hexagonal porcelain tile](https://www.tileshop.com/products/hex-gloss-white-porcelain-mosaic-tile-2-x-2-in-615822) and there is a very noticeable collection of black dots on all tiles (see below) after wiping. Nothing seems to take it out from alcohol, toothpaste, soap, vinegar, backing soda, ...

This seems like a serious defect **in the tile** to me. I've used other porcelain tile with colors very contrastive to the grout and have not had such an issue. I am wondering if I am correct and looking for ways to fix it. Should I seek a full replacement or do I have to go it alone and clean all these tiny tiles without disturbing the grout (if it is even possible to clean them. It seems to me that the grout is now filling these voids and it is impossible to get out without something maybe more corrosive that would also ruin the tile)?

[image: Example of marked tile]

Comment: Seems more like a fault of the tile surface not being smooth than a fault of the grout getting trapped in (apparently) pits on the surface of the tile. I've used black grout (don't recall the brand offhand) and it cleaned up just fine from my tiles.

Comment: @Ecnerwal yeah, clearly there is some exceptionally small pitting in the finish. I was definitely not expecting this of course. I've used other porcelain tile with colors very contrastive to the grout and have not had such an issue

Comment: You could try a grout cleaner and see what comes off, but I fear you're stuck with something on the tile. My opinion is that it doesn't look bad...

Comment: With tile that has pin holes in the glaze you can never get them clean once the grout gets in the holes, the grout color would not last long if you could wipe it out but the inferior tile glazing was the root cause, I see a lot of this low quality at the big box stores, sorry to say that but they have the least expensive products. I have returned 50% of the tiles in the past actually bought 2x to be able to pick the good and return the bad, the employee said how can we sell these. I agreed with him and said that’s why I was bringing so much back.